# Menu active background dynamic for nav bar

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation

[image]

I need a menu where I can add different dynamic backgrounds for active menu.

Heres the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErikP/MNDTb/9/) but I could not get it to remove other background image when one is activated.

```
$(function () {
    // Init Content
    var activeMenu = $('#1');
    activeMenu.toggleClass('active1');
    $('#main').load('http://www.legaus.de/PICS/1.html');


    $('#1').click(function () {
        $('#1').removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("active1");
        $('#main').load('http://www.legaus.de/PICS/1.html');
    });


    $('#2').click(function () {
        $('#2').removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("active2");
        $('#main').load('http://www.legaus.de/PICS/2.html');
    });


    $('#3').click(function () {
        $('#3').removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("active3");
        $('#main').load('http://www.legaus.de/PICS/3.html');
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to every `click` listener

```
$('#1, #2, #3').removeClass();
```

so that every time you click an element remove the class from the others

like this :

```
$('#1').click(function () {
    $('#2, #3').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("active1");
    $('#main').load('http://www.legaus.de/PICS/1.html');
});


$('#2').click(function () {
    $('#1, #3').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("active2");
    $('#main').load('http://www.legaus.de/PICS/2.html');
});


$('#3').click(function () {
    $('#1, #2').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("active3");
    $('#main').load('http://www.legaus.de/PICS/3.html');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MNDTb/16/)

Comment: Could shorten a bit by replacing the 3 removeClass()'s with :
    $('#1, #2, #3').removeClass();

Comment: @nick True i edited. And even shorter dont remove the class from the clicked one

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to remove the background image when we click on something else, isn't it?.If that's the case then,I have updated the code check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MNDTb/17/).we just remove the class from all other li's e.g

```
 $('#1').click(function () {
        $('#2').removeClass("active2");
        $('#3').removeClass("active3");
        $(this).addClass("active1");
        $('#main').load('http://www.legaus.de/PICS/1.html');
    });
```

Hope that helps.